# Trying to produce different result from following recursive permutation function

Tags: c++, algorithm

The following code produces the first string(multiple times) plus the all possible permutations of the second string. I'm trying to produce the permutations of first string(instead of second) plus the second string. How can I do that?

```
void permute(string prefix, string rest)
{

if (rest == "")
{
    cout << prefix << endl;
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++)
    {
        //test if rest[i] is unique.
        bool found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (rest[j] == rest[i])
                found = true;
        }
        if (found)
            continue;
        string newPrefix = prefix + rest[i];
        string newRest = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1);
        permute(newPrefix, newRest);

    }

 }
}

int main()
{
 permute("T", "MAC");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<algorithm>` header has functions for permutation enumeration.

```
void permute( std::string const & prefix, std::string const & rest ) {
    std::string perm = prefix;

    do {
        std::cout << perm << rest << '\n';
        std::next_permutation( perm.begin(), perm.end() );
    } while ( perm != prefix );
}
```